# JSF 2.x + Spring 3.2 Integration?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jsf-2, richfaces

Sorry to ask this question and it may be a duplicate of other similar threads in Stack overflow.Those similar thready does not work in my situation.

I am having a quite enough knowledge in **spring 3.2** and completed one small project in **spring**.

Now I am new to **JSF** and I some created basic JSF example .I would like to use the `JSF` features and its `components` for my new **Spring + JSF** project.

The links that I came out for **JSF + Spring Integration** are given below ,

http://papweb.wordpress.com/2011/07/29/spring-mvc-3-jsf-2-with-maven-2-and-tomcat/

http://blog.terrencemiao.com/archives/spring-3-shacks-up-jsf-2-the-maverick-way

The resources I found , does not helped me and that was very **old** post.

Can any one provide me a sample Integration for **JSF 2.X + Spring 3.x MVC with controller and view resolver** and this would help a lot of users who really seeking for a working one..

Hope our stack users will help me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all: you shouldn't use JSF and Spring MVC together since they compete against each other! (That's my opinion!)

Take a look at these links:

- [JSF 2.0 + Spring integration example](http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/jsf-2-0-spring-integration-example/)
- [Integrating Spring Web Flow with JSF](http://www.javabeat.net/2010/11/integrating-spring-web-flow-with-jsf/)
- [Configuring Spring MVC for use with JSF 2](http://static.springsource.org/spring-webflow/docs/2.2.x/reference/html/ch13s05.html)

Comment: Thanks for a quick reply . May I know why should I don't use it together ?

Comment: Is it possible to integrate both or not ? any other alternatives ?

Comment: But ,  In that example they don't use spring controller.Because in my application where I need to write my business logic ? I already done the business logic in my spring controller.

Comment: and what part of jsf do you want?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36641/discussion-between-kite-player-and-philipp-sander)

Answer (score 6):

In my opinion, `Spring` and `JSF` - both could be used just fine. It, of course, mostly depends on your requirements and preferences of using those frameworks.

Spring - it has very nice ways of [transactions management](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.8/reference/transaction.html), [dependency injection](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.8/reference/transaction.html), [security](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/tutorial.html) and many other features, however - plain `JSF` does not provide this kind of features out of the box, but JSF has very nice way of rendering views.  So these features from both frameworks mixed up together could result in simplicity.  JSF has a variety of it's frameworks which are built on it, like:

- [Primefaces](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/home.jsf)
- [RichFaces](http://showcase.richfaces.org/)
- [IceFaces](http://icefaces-showcase.icesoft.org/showcase.jsf)

In my opinion, you could simplify your views development, if you had been using `JSF`. JSF has [ManagedBean](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnaqm.html)(s), which depending on your configuration serves your requests, like 
Spring controllers does.

Actual configuration is pretty straight forward. You need to have:

`faces-config.xml` file which contains [SpringBeanFacesELResolver](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/jsf/el/SpringBeanFacesELResolver.html):

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<faces-config xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
              xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
              xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_0.xsd"
              version="2.0">

    <application>
        <el-resolver>org.springframework.web.jsf.el.SpringBeanFacesELResolver</el-resolver>
    </application>

    <navigation-rule>
        <!-- your rules here -->
    </navigation-rule>

</faces-config>
```

Spring `applicationCotext.xml` file.  Usual spring config, nothing `JSF` specific.

Your `web.xml` which should look something like this:

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
         version="3.0">

    <!-- other config -->

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
        <param-value>Production</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <!-- other of config -->

</web-app>
```

The most pretty cool thing in `JSF` is [View Scope](http://balusc.blogspot.co.uk/2010/06/benefits-and-pitfalls-of-viewscoped.html), which would be lost by default, if you had been using `JSF` with `Spring`, but definitely you don't want to lose it. [This](http://comdynamics.net/blog/109/spring3-jsf2-view-scope/) explains how to make View Scope work in `JSF` and `Spring` integration.

If I would be building some application from scratch, I would choose these two frameworks and integrate them together, but this is just my opinion. Hope this clears some things for you.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.But how can I get the value in the `JSF` view page that I already put **model.addAttribute("some", someObject);** in the `spring` controller.

Comment: You don't have to use spring model anymore, you have to use JSF ManagedBeans. Ditch spring MVC stuff from your application, use JSF for controller layer and spring for transaction management, dependency injection, etc.