# alternative of @ApplicationScoped annotation in JSF

Tags: jsf

I am using `@ManageBean` with `@ApplicationScoped` and `@SessionScoped` annotation in MyFaces 2.1.5 version and i am not able to set the scope of bean. Can you please suggest any alternative of `@ApplicationScoped` and `@SessionScoped` annotation.

Comment: You need to form the question a bit bit better. Tell us exactly what you are trying to do and maybe post some actual code.

Comment: Use "faces-config.xml" instead.

Comment: Well, if alternative is what you want to hear then you can always go with Spring, it integrates nicely with JSF ;) @Component @Scope("session") (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18527409/jsf-2-x-spring-3-2-integration)